# invoking a rake task inside a rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a rake task inside a scheduler like below

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.start

schedule.schedule(chron) do
puts "in scheduler"
begin
ENV['RAILS_ENV']='production'
Rake::Task['connection'].invoke
rescue Exception => e
puts "error"
end
```

the rake task is executed only for the first time. but the scheduler seem to be running in the given interval.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: which version of Ruby ? Passenger, Thin, Mongrel ? What does "seem to be running mean" ?

Also take the time to read : http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html and http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 2):

Rake is a dependency processor.  It runs a task only once unless you tell it otherwise.  See http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html#M000115  You need to

```
def force_invoke(task)
  task.reenable
  task.invoke
end
```